# Imperative Call Using Await In LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, asynchronous

Is it possible to imperatively call a function from a wired function using `async/await`? And yes, I've seen similar questions - but they kinda miss the point I'm trying to make.

Consider this simple example:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: RECORD_FIELDS })
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else if (data) {
        fetchMoreData({ recordId: data.fields.Id.value })
            .then((data) => {
                doStuff();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

I find this hard to read and more error-prone compared to the version using `await`:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: RECORD_FIELDS })
async wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else if (data) {
        try {
            const moreData = await fetchMoreData({ recordId: data.fields.Id.value });
            doStuff();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

But the second version needs `async` to be added to `wiredRecord` which a) doesn't really do anything because `@wire` makes this already "async" by design (as the framework calls it when needed) and b) nobody uses it. But it gets even worse if you stitch multiple calls together - it makes it even harder to read.

Is this the only way of accomplishing this? And if it is - is there a downside to it?

Answer (score 5):

`@wire` doesn't make the function `async`. To be `async` means to behave like a `Promise`. In other words, a function marked with this keyword transforms from:

```
async method() {
  try {
    const result = await doSomething();
    return result;
  } catch(e) {
    handleError(e);
  }
}
```

to something like:

```
method() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    doSomething().then(resolve).catch((e) => {
      handleError(e);
      reject(e);
    })
  );
}
```

As far as making it more legible, use early returns when appliable.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: RECORD_FIELDS })
async wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
    if(!data) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        const moreData = await fetchMoreData({ recordId: data.fields.Id.value });
        doStuff();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you can do multiple things in a single try-catch:

```
    try {
        const moreData = await fetchMoreData({ recordId: data.fields.Id.value });
        doStuff();
        const yetMoreData = await fetchEvenMoreData(params);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

That's the advantage of using `async` over traditional promises.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I updated my answer to put the "async" in quotes with a short explanation in brackets. My question revolved more around whether I should use `async` for an already wired function as I see nobody using it that way.

Comment: @Semmel It's an uncommon construction in publicly available code, I'd agree. That said, if its your project, and you have control, there's nothing wrong with using async/await.

Answer (score 1):

You can call another async method from the wired function by passing required parameters.

```js
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: RECORD_FIELDS })
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else if (data) {
        this.processResponse(data.fields.Id.value)
    }
}

async processResponse(recordId){
    try {
        const moreData = await fetchMoreData({ recordId });
        //doStuff();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this as it untangles the wiring for `getRecord` from processing the response which might include other calls that I can now use with `await` in the second function.